# Arithmetic-geometric mean, prove that $c_n = 4me^{-\ell 2^n+\epsilon_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $a$ and $b$ reals with $a > b > 0$. Let $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ with $a_0 = a$, $b_0 = b$ and

$$a_{n+1} = \tfrac{a_n+b_n}{2} \quad\text{;}\quad b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_nb_n}$$

We know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} a_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} b_n = m$.

Let $c_n = \sqrt{a_n^2-b_n^2}$.

We know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} c_n =0$ and that $c_{n+1} \leq \frac{c_n^2}{4m}$.

The question is to prove that there is $\ell > 0$ and $\epsilon_n > 0$ with $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \epsilon_n = 0$ such as

$$c_n = 4me^{-\ell 2^n+\epsilon_n}$$

An indication is to use $u_n = -2^{-n} \ln(c_n)$ and $\sum (u_{n+1}-u_n)$.

Comment: Give me the original statement, @MB78

Comment: @GuillemusCallelus The question is "Prove that there is a real $\ell >0$ and a sequence $(\epsilon_n)$ with $\epsilon_n > 0$ for all integer $n$ such as $c_n = 4me^{-\ell 2^n+\epsilon_n}$." (with the indication I wrote in the main subject)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $c_{n+1} = \frac{c_n^2}{2(a_n+b_n)} = \frac{c_n^2}{4a_{n+1}}$, we get.
\begin{align*}
u_{n+1} & = -2^{-n-1} \ln(c_{n+1}) \\
& = -2^{-n-1} (\ln(c_n)-\ln(4a_{n+1})) \\
& = u_n+2^{-n-1} \ln(4a_{n+1})
\end{align*}

$\ln(4a_{n+1}) = \ln(4m)+\underbrace{\ln(\frac{4a_{n+1}}{4m})}_{\alpha_n}$. The sequence $(\alpha_n)$ is positive and decreasing to zero.

$$ u_n-u_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( u_{k+1}-u_k \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k-1} \left( \ln(4m)+\alpha_k \right) $$

Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k-1} = 1-2^{-n}$, we get.

$$ u_n = u_0+\ln(4m)-2^{-n} \ln(4m)+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k-1} \alpha_k $$

Since $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k-1} \alpha_k \leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^{-k-1} \alpha_0 \leqslant \alpha_0 \left( 1-2^{-n} \right)$, we get.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{+ \infty} 2^{-k-1} \alpha_k = S \quad\text{with}\quad 0 < S \leqslant \alpha_0 $$

Now, the rest.

$$ R_n = \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} 2^{-k-1} \alpha_k \leqslant \alpha_n \sum_{k=n}^{+\infty} 2^{-k-1} \leqslant 2^{-n}\alpha_n $$

Finally.

\begin{align*}
u_n & = u_0+\ln(4m)-2^{-n} \ln(4m)+S-R_n \\
& = u_0+\ln(4m)+S-2^{-n} \left( \ln(4m)+2^nR_n \right)
\end{align*}

Let $\ell = u_0+\ln(4m)+S$ and $\varepsilon_n = 2^nR_n$.

The last problem is to prove that $\ell > 0$.

As $u_n = -2^{-n} \ln(c_n)$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} c_n = 0$, $u_n > 0$ after some rank and so $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} u_n = \ell \geq 0$. If $\ell = 0$, $c_n = 4me^{\varepsilon_n}$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} c_n = 4m \ne 0$. So $\ell \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have knowledge of theta fuctions, use the parametrization
$$ a_n = m\theta_3(q^{2^{n+1}})^2,\;
 b_n = m\theta_4(q^{2^{n+1}})^2,\;
 c_n = m\theta_2(q^{2^{n+1}})^2$$
for some $q$ which comes from the identity $\theta_3(q)^4=\theta_4(q)^4+\theta_2(q)^4$. By power series expansion
$$ c_n = 4m(q^{2^n} +2q^{52^n}+q^{92^n}+\cdots)$$
and so the rest is comparatively easy.

Using the suggested approach, we get the following. Without loss of generality, let $m=1$, since the
AGM is homogeneous. Next, let $t_n := -\ln(c_n/4)/2^n$, (minus to make $t_n>0$). We know$$c_{n+1} = c_n^2/(4a_{n+1}) \quad \textrm{and}\quad
 \ln(a_{n+1})/2^{n+1} = t_{n+1} - t_n.$$
Using the inequalities $a_0 > a_1 > \cdots>1,\;$ we know that $t_0 <t_1< \dots\;$ is increasing sequence but $\ln(a_0)/2^{n+1}>t_{n+1}-t_n$ and so $t_n\to t$ for some $t>0$. Summing the telescoping series we get
$$t -t_n = \sum_{k>n} \ln(a_{k})/2^k  \quad \textrm{and}\quad 
\ln(a_0)/2^n >t -t_n > 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't use this because I don't know anything about theta functions. I have to use the $(u_n)$ sequence.

Comment: Ok, I should have guessed, but you may be able to use $c_n=4m(q^{2^n}+2q^{52^n}+\cdots)$ without knowing theta functions.

Comment: Perhaps, but I need to prove that $(c_n)$ follow this expression. Actually I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

As I assumed, the statement is not clear. Only the first two lines are the hypotheses. I'll do it tomorrow:

$a_{n+1} = \tfrac{a_n+b_n}{2}, b_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_nb_n}\rightarrow$ (arithmetic mean > geometric mean)

$0<b<b_{1}<a_{1}<a,\quad 0<b<b_{1}<b_{2}<a_{2}<a_{1}<a, \quad \text{etc.}\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             a_{n} \quad \text{is decreasing} \\
             \\ b_{n} \quad \text{is increasing}
             \end{array}
   \right.$

$\{a_{n}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$ monotones and bounded $\rightarrow$ They are convergent $\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \exists \lim_{n\to \infty}\{a_{n}\}=m \\
             \\ \exists \lim_{n\to \infty}\{a_{n}\}=n
             \end{array}
   \right.$

$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_{n}+b_{n}}{2}\rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{a_{n}+b_{n}}{2}\rightarrow m=\dfrac{m+n}{2}$ 
$\rightarrow m=n\rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\{a_{n}\}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\{b_{n}\}=m$

$a_{n}$ is increasing $\rightarrow a_{n}\geq m$

$c_{n}=\sqrt{a_{n}^{2}-b_{n}^{2}}\rightarrow c_{n}^{2}=(a_{n}-b_{n})(a_{n}+b_{n})$

$c_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n+1}^{2}-b_{n+1}^{2}}=\sqrt{\left( \frac{a_{n}+b_{n}}{2}\right)^{2}-(\sqrt{a_{n}b_{n}})^{2}}$ 
$\rightarrow c_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{a_{n}^{2}+2a_{n}b_{n}+b_{n}^{2}-4a_{n}b_{n}}{4}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{(a_{n}-b_{n})^{2}}=\dfrac{1}{2}(a_{n}-b_{n})$

$\rightarrow c_{n+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{c_{n}^{2}}{(a_{n}+b_{n})}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{c_{n}^{2}}{2a_{n}}\leq \dfrac{c_{n}^{2}}{4m}\rightarrow c_{n+1}\leq \dfrac{c_{n}^{2}}{4m}$

You've understood?

EDIT:

It defines: $u_{n}=-2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}=-2^{-n-1}\ln(c_{n+1})$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}=-2^{-n-1}\ln\left( \frac{c_{n}^{2}}{4a_{n+1}}\right)$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}=-2^{-n-1}[2\ln(c_{n})-\ln(4a_{n+1})]=-2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})+2^{-n-1}\ln(4a_{n+1})$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}=u_{n}+2^{-n-1}\ln(4a_{n+1})$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}-u_{n}=2^{-n-1}\left[ \ln(4m)+\ln\left( \frac{4a_{n+1}}{4m}\right)\right]$

$\rightarrow u_{n+1}-u_{n}=2^{-n-1}\left[ \ln(4m)+\ln\left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{m}\right)\right]$;

we put: $a_{n+1}=\ln\left( \frac{a_{n+1}}{m}\right)\rightarrow \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             a_{n} \quad \text{decreases} \\
             \\ a_{n}>0 \\
             \\ \lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=0
             \end{array}
   \right.$

$u_{n}-u_{0}=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}(u_{k+1}-u_{k})$

$\rightarrow -2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})-[-2^{-0}\ln(c_{0})]=\sum^{n}_{k=0}\left[2^{-k-1}[\ln(4m)+\alpha_{k+1}]\right]$

$\rightarrow -2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})+\ln \sqrt{a-b}=\ln(4m)\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{1}{2^{k+1}}+\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}$

$\rightarrow 2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})=-\ln(4m)\cdot \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)}{1-\frac{1}{2}}+\ln \sqrt{a-b}-\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}$

$\rightarrow 2^{-n}\ln(c_{n})=-\dfrac{2^{n}-1}{2^{n}}\ln(4m)-\ln \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a-b}}-2^{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}$

$\rightarrow \ln(c_{n})=\ln(4m)-2^{n}\left( \ln \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a-b}}+\ln 4m\right)-2^{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}$

$\rightarrow \ln(c_{n})=\ln(4m)-2^{n}\ln \dfrac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}-2^{n}\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}$

Where $\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}=K$, since 
$\dfrac{\frac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}}{\frac{\alpha_{k}}{2^{k}}}=\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2\alpha_{k}}<1$ (Quotient criterion)

$\rightarrow \beta_{n}=K-\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}\dfrac{\alpha_{k+1}}{2^{k+1}}, \quad \text{with}\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}\beta_{n}=0$

$\rightarrow \ln(c_{n})=\ln(4m)-2^{n}\ln \dfrac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}-2^{n}(K-\beta_{n})$

$\rightarrow \ln(c_{n})=\ln(4m)-2^{n}\left( \ln \frac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}+K\right)-2^{n}\beta_{n}$

Let $l=\ln \dfrac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}+K>0$:
$$c_{n}=4me^{-2^{n}l-2^{n}\beta_{n}}$$

Comment: Tanks for answer, but I already proved all of this in previous questions. The actual question was to prove that $c_n = 4me^{-\ell 2^n+\epsilon_n}$. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: I'll do it tomorrow.

Comment: I've edited my post to had new results.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but: I'm staying here!

Comment: Tanks, I was on the same way, but how do you know that $\ln \dfrac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}+K>0$ ? I know that $K > 0$ but I think that $\ln \dfrac{4m}{\sqrt{a-b}}$ may be negative.

Comment: Indeed. An over view.

Comment: I have $K > \ln \sqrt{\frac{a+b}{m}}$ but it give nothing more for me.

Comment: And in your text, I think that $\ln(c_0) = \ln\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$.

Comment: What a failure, I have done. This question is making me nervous.

Comment: Thank for help. I think I've got the proof that $\ell >0$. I made an answer for that.